# Objective C remove trailing zeros after decimal place

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I am trying to get number in 2 decimal places with trailing zeros.

e.g

```
 11.633-> 11.63
 11.630-> 11.63
 11.60-> 11.6
 11-> 11
 12928.98-> 12928.98
```

for this I written below line

```
 #define kFloatFormat2(x) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", x] floatValue]]

    NSNumber *number1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:12928.98];
    NSLog(@"number1:%@", number1);
    NSString *string1 = kFloatFormat2([number1 floatValue]);
    NSLog(@"string1:%@", string1);
```

the output of above prints

number1:12928.98

string1:12929

Why it prints 12929 value for string1
I want it as 12928.98.

Comment: You might also consider using an (inline) function rather than a macro to avoid all kinds of potential problems.

Comment: Why not just use `NSNumberFormatter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using a number formatter?

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:NO];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:fractionDigits];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:fractionDigits];
```

Now do something like

```
NSNumber *x = @23423;
NSString *value = [formatter stringFromNumber:x];
NSLog(@"number = %@, value);
```

Answer (score 3):

You macro makes no sense. Just make it:

```
#define kFloatFormat2(x) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [x floatValue]]
```

where `x` is an `NSNumber`. And then you would call it like this:

```
NSString *string1 = kFloatFormat2(number1);
```

Or just do this:

```
double x = 12928.98;
NSLog(@"number = %.2f", x);
```

Comment: Can you do `%f` with a `NSNumber`?

Comment: @Rich No. That's an object so you must use `%@`. The only way to use `%f` with an `NSNumber` is to call `floatValue` or `doubleValue` on the `NSNumber` object.

Comment: I didn't think so - "where x is an NSNumber." and then you had `%f` You've corrected your answer now anyway!

Comment: @Rich Yeah, as I was typing my response to your comment I realized why you asked it. Thanks. :)